# How to implement two languages or more in my website in Laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, localization

Actually I want to make my website to support two languages or more in Laravel, I know some ways like make the website based (in design) for one language, lets say English, and modify the CSS based upon the Session language direction, and also change the float and so on ...

Second way to make two separates design and swap between them.

I wonder how to make my website to support both languages in Laravel, I think it's related to (localization feature in Laravel): http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization

But I don't how to use it, any tips or suggestion to do this task in my website?

Comment: There are a lot of approaches. You can check this one for instance. http://slick.pl/kb/laravel/localization-in-laravel-5/

Comment: Take a look [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website) Its an great example to look at/ read to get into localization.